# Indicate when a link was added in edit review

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

So I review a [suggested edit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/824) on UX.SE, skim down to the edited bits, and this greets me:

[image]

Yes, the highlighted bits are completely identical. But if you *hover* over the text, you'll find the text on the right gets an underline. What happened here is the user added links to the highlighted words. I see this fairly often.

Would it be possible to make it more clear when an edit added links to body text? It seems like showing the link color (blue in this case) over the highlight color might be enough, but I'm not sure that works as well across all sites (for instance, on Programmers links are red, red links on a green highlight would be bad).

Comment: Now, the edit message in this case does mention they added links, but they might not always. Plus I usually ignore the reason and see what they actually changed.

Comment: You choose not to use the second icon on the left sidebar there? The one that shows the source?

Comment: @random should I have to view the source and examine the raw markdown of every single revision? There's a reason markdown view isn't the default. Edits should be easy to spot and revise.

Comment: It becomes default if it's the last view you used

Comment: This is what the edit description is for. It says "added links". They probably added some links.

Comment: I would actually argue this is just a bug. Strangely, the HTML output generates a `.diff-add` block *inside* the `a` element (ie the link). The link wasn't there in the old version, so the diff span should contain the link rather than the other way around. Then presumably the `color` would also not be changed, and the problem would be solved.